# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' on SQ Lite

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, dart

I am working sqlite databases and trying fetch data from sqlite file. I copied my database with no error. But when i am trying to fetch data to show on my app, datas coming null. I was debug my code and trying to understand where is the problem but i don't get it. So can you guys help me?

```
class StudentsModel {
  final int studentId;
  final String studentName;
  final String studentEmail;

  StudentsModel({required this.studentId, required this.studentName, required this.studentEmail});
}
```

Here its my model page and

```
  Future<List<StudentsModel>?> getAllStudents() async {
    var db = await DatabaseCopy.databaseAccess();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOfStudents = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM students");
    return List.generate(listOfStudents.length, (index) {
      var row = listOfStudents[index];
      return StudentsModel(
        studentId: row["student_id"],
        studentName: row["student_name"],
        studentEmail: row["student_email"],
      );
    });
  }
```

My repository page.
[Here the console error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaYcE.png)
Thanks!

Guys new update. When am trying to search students from database, it works but the problem is showing all students to homepage. I am adding new things to understand problem.

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<HomepageCubit>().loadAllStudents();
  }
```

and this is part of trying to show all students in homepage

```dart
body: BlocBuilder<HomepageCubit, List<StudentsModel>>(
          builder: (context, studentsList) {
            if (studentsList.isNotEmpty) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: studentsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var student = studentsList[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => StudentDetailPage(
                            studentsModel: student,
                          ),
                        ),
```

and the last part is homepage cubit

```dart
class HomepageCubit extends Cubit<List<StudentsModel>> {
  HomepageCubit() : super(<StudentsModel>[]);

  final sRepo = StudentsRepository();

  Future<void> loadAllStudents() async {
    final allStudentsList = await sRepo.getAllStudents();
    emit(allStudentsList!);
  }
```

Comment: Did you find al least the "area" where the problem may be located? For example, sRepo.getAllStudents() returns some data or not? If not, did you try to put a breakpoint on the "studentId: row["student_id"]," row? Does the execution reach that point? If yes, which is the result of "row["student_id"]" expression? Is it null?

Comment: how can be possible i cant understand it.  Searching students code and showAllStudents methods are same but the main problem is showAllStudents in the homepage. I am gonna try the debug my code again. I will be back soon with results.

Comment: The error shown in the image you linked seems caused by the assignment studentName: row["student_name"] or studentEmail: row["student_email"] where you are trying to assign a Null value to a non-nullable String. I think that the data retrieved form the db is null or has some missing values in some fields of some entries.

Comment: For example, if a student has no email, the student_email field will be null so you can not assign that value to a String variable. In that case you should declare studentEmail as String? type, which is nullable

Comment: I guess i am gonna add new database from db browser to my project. Because the main problem is coming from my database.

Comment: I didn't understand... did you find the solution?

Comment: yes bro i got the problem and solve it. I'm gonna edit my post to understand how i solve it. thanks for help i am appricate it.

Comment: I’m glad I could help out 

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. You guys be careful working with DB Browser. So the main problem is so ridicilous. When I created a new database, I clicked View data and accidentally created a new blank line. So I couldn't show blank data on the screen because the data from the first line was empty, but I was able to search.